# Increasing text size in Seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using Seaborn's jointplot to generate some scatterplots.

Here is a sample of what I have done, and its outcome:

```
from scipy import stats

x = np.arange(100) + np.random.randn(100)*20
y = np.arange(100) + np.random.randn(100)*20

g = sb.JointGrid(x, y, ratio=100)
g.plot_joint(sb.regplot)
g.annotate(stats.spearmanr)
g.ax_marg_x.set_axis_off()
g.ax_marg_y.set_axis_off()
plt.xlabel('X', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize=18)
plt.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=18)
plt.legend(fontsize=20)
```

Here is the resulting plot.

How can I change the size of the text displayed in the plot (text for the correlation coefficient and the p-value)?

[image]

Comment: Adding `matplotlib.rc("legend", fontsize=20)` right after the imports seems to work fine here.

Comment: @cel Will this affect any other plots that I will generate?

Comment: Yes it would, but you could use a context manager (`matplotlib.rc_context`) to only set it for one plot.

Comment: Note, that AFAIK using `rc_context` overwrites `seaborn`'s default plotting style and you have to call `set_style` explicitly.

Comment: Why do you say that? `rc_context` by design only sets the particular params you define and otherwise inherits params from the global context.

Answer (score 3):

This example from Seaborn page explains it well.

```
g = sns.JointGrid(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g = g.plot_joint(plt.scatter,
             color="g", s=40, edgecolor="white")
g = g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, kde=False, color="g")
rsquare = lambda a, b: stats.pearsonr(a, b)[0] ** 2
g = g.annotate(rsquare, template="{stat}: {val:.2f}",
           stat="$R^2$", loc="upper left", fontsize=12)
```

Hence you can just try this

```
g = sns.jointplot(x="", y="", data=df,kind='reg');
g = g.annotate(stats.pearsonr, fontsize=18)
```